# Cannot pass list in udf argument in Pyspark

Tags: python, list, pyspark

I have the following Pyspark registered function:

```
@f.udf(returnType=StringType())
def func_TEST(s, input_list):
    l = list((s[0+i:5+i] for i in range(0, len(s), 5)))
    output = ""

    for input_i in input_list:
        for input_j in input_i:
            if(next(iter(filter(lambda x: x.startswith(input_j), l)), None)):
                output = output + next(iter(filter(lambda x: x.startswith(input_j), l)), None)
                break
        output = output + " "       
    return output
```

And I have the following list:

```
ABM_string =[["BS-", "CA#", "CA-"], ["VS-", "SE#", "SE-" ], ["EN-"], ["TR-"], ["DGA"], ["DR-"], ["ABM"]]
```

What I'm trying to do is to pass ABM_string as an argument into func_TEST's second argument.

I've done the following:

```
x = x.withColumn("column_2", trim((func_TEST(col("column"),*ABM_string))))
```

But I keep getting the following error: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o708.withColumn.

Comment: why use the `*` unpacker? just input the whole list

Comment: I can't because then I get an error: Invalid argument, not a string or column: [['BS-', 'CA#', 'CA-'], ['VS-', 'SE#', 'SE-'], ['EN-'], ['TR-'], ['DGA'], ['DR-'], ['ABM']] of type <class 'list'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.